# Is "change from .. line to .. line (at a station)" correct?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to tell someone to change trains at a station.
Is this correct?

> At Kinshicho station, please change from the Sobu Line to the Hanzomon Line.

Should I use "transfer"?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say *switch the track*, maybe!

Comment: If you are just changing trains on the same railway, I would just use "change". Also OK if you are changing service levels (local/rapid etc.). If you are changing railways, then use transfer (the intent is that you have to get another ticket, though that is not always the case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use the verb to *[transfer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transfer)* as it means:

> to change from one vehicle or transportation line to another

Your example:

> Please transfer to the Hanzomon Line from the Sobu Line at Kinshicho
>   station.

You can place "at Kinshicho station" at the beginning.